# How to wrap an external API inside a custom API with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, maven

Let's say I have a third party rest api ("https://example.com/write") that allows POST requests with the following body structure:

```
{
"id": "abc",
"Config": {"Comments":"text"}
}
```

I am completely new to Java and the Spring Framework, but I want to create a custom API with Spring  that **only** allow users to change the **text** part of the body. Other parts of the JSON body should have a fixed value (for example id is always "abc"). Basically, when user input a custom text string, my api will compile the input and consume the external api and get the results from it accordingly

I understand the basics of @Getmapping / @RequestMapping after doing some research. Here is what I have so far for my custom API, and I am stuck at the post mapping section.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")

public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

 // GET
 @RequestMapping(value = "/retrive", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrive (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // URL
        URL u = new URL("https://example.com/get");
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

        // Create HttpHeaders for ResponseEntity
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        uc.setRequestProperty ("Authentication", "Bearer "+ env.getProperty("api-key")); 

        try (InputStream inputStream = uc.getInputStream();
             OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    )
        {IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

 // POST
 @RequestMapping(value = "/write", method = { RequestMethod.POST },
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
      public ResponseEntity process(@RequestBody Root input) throws IOException {
      
      // Operation goes here...       

       return new ResponseEntity<>(input, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

public class Root{
  private String Comments;

// Getters and Setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom DTO class which will represent the response from Third party API. What It means is it should have all fields which should map with corresponding required field of response payload of third party API. It will be populated on de-serializing the third party API response. You can take help of feign client here. Its very easy and declarative way to make REST API call.

Create a separate response DTO with 2 fields 1 which will have the static value and second the DTO which we created above (which will be populated with the response of third party API). This DTO will be the response from POST "/write"